# How to place two elements side by side in one div?

Tags: html, css

I have loop that goes trough all pictures that I have and displays them. I would like to display them in one row, from left to right, but with css that I have is displaying them one under other. I have use flow but not sure if I used it correctly.

Here is my code:

```css
.column.is-narrow {
  float: right;
}
.box {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="columns" ng-repeat="a in $ctrl.f">
    <div class="column is-narrow">
      <div class="box" style="width: 200px;">
        <p class="title is-5">{{album}}</p>
        <figure class="image is-128x128">
          <!--<img ng-src="{{src}}"> remove and replaced for demo purpose-->
          <img src="http://dummyimage.com/128x128" />
        </figure>
        <p class="subtitle">{{person}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I am aware that my css is not correct I have been searching for answer but couldn't find it.

Comment: your structure is imbricated, to have 2 elements side by side, you should first make them sibbling not parent/child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer and it was pretty simple :) 
I just had to add one more div with class with which I will float it to left. This is what I wanted:

.html

```
 <div class="column">
      <div class="columns">
      <div class="float" ng-repeat="a in $ctrl.f"> /* added this line of code */
        <div class="column is-narrow">
          <div class="box" style="width: 200px;">
            <p class="title is-5">{{album}}</p>
            <figure class="image is-128x128">
              <!--<img ng-src="{{src}}"> remove and replaced for demo purpose-->
              <img src="http://dummyimage.com/128x128" />
            </figure>
            </div>
            </div>
            <p class="subtitle">{{person}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

.css

```
.float{
    float:left;
}
```

That was it. It's working. :)

Answer (score 4):

Basically, when you float things, they'll still wrap if there isn't enough space to display both side by side. The easiest solution is to set a width on them to ensure that their container will always be wide enough to fit the content. You can do it with percentages or pixels, depending on your use case.

Note: If you use percentages, percentages adding up to 100% may still cause it to wrap, because they may not take into account padding, margin and/or border depending on other things. I usually do something like `49%` for both, then float one right and one left.

Comment: Or make use of `box-sizing: border-box;` to fix the issue with the border putting extra pixels.

Comment: I still don't get it... but pictures are displayed in same div

Comment: @uom-pgregorio Even if you do that, it won't always fix the issues with margins, which are the most common culprit. You CAN get around it, but it's usually easier to fudge it. Another case is where you have an odd pixel, 50%, 50% will have a rounding error and still be one pixel too large in some scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

You may use display and mind this inline-style `<div class="box" style="width: 200px;">` wich is to start with, not wide enough to hold texts and img side by side

- `display:table`/`table-cell;`

```css
.column.is-narrow {
  float: right;
}
.box {display:table;}
.box> p, .box> figure {display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle/* or top or else */
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="columns" ng-repeat="a in $ctrl.f">
    <div class="column is-narrow">
      <div class="box" style="width: 200px;">
        <p class="title is-5">{{album}}</p>
        <figure class="image is-128x128">
          <!--<img ng-src="{{src}}"> remove and replaced for demo purpose-->
          <img src="http://dummyimage.com/128x128" />
        </figure>
        <p class="subtitle">{{person}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

- `display:flex;`

```css
.column.is-narrow {
  float: right;
}
.box {
  display: flex;
  /* removed width:200px from inline-style*/
}
p {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="columns" ng-repeat="a in $ctrl.f">
    <div class="column is-narrow">
      <div class="box">
        <p class="title is-5">{{album}}</p>
        <figure class="image is-128x128">
          <!--<img ng-src="{{src}}"> remove and replaced for demo purpose-->
          <img src="http://dummyimage.com/128x128" />
        </figure>
        <p class="subtitle">{{person}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I want it to be displayed one picture next to other. It's not about album name or person in div. But to display to pictures containing album name, src and person next to each other. My code has loop that displays all picture. So I want to apply correct css to display that loop pictures one next to other. So pictures and not album, picture and person that all represents one picture. :)

Comment: @user3599620 okay, can you update your snippet with pieces of html missing (not the {{things to loop}} so it is easier to see your issue. Beside, do you need those boxes to wrap at one point and being stretched/shrinked in berween break points ? However, the display:flex or table works, apply it two level upper  to `.columns`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to declare the parent div as a flex container by setting the property `display: flex` and `flex-direction:row`. If you don't want to wrap your pictures, you can set `flex-wrap:nowrap`.
Here http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/  is nice playground for flex box.